# Google Cloud Functions Firebase Error The default Firebase app already exists

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Functions to write to a Firebase Realtime database (not firestore).

I keep getting an error on the 2nd (second) time the cloud function executes. The first time is OK. But always fails on the 2nd and 3rd and onwards.

Error Message: "The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument."

Here is my code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db

def my_function(request):

    firebase_admin.initialize_app()
    firebase_db_path = "/some_path"
    ref = db.reference(path = firebase_db_path, app=None, url = "https://blah-blah.firebaseio.com/")
    ref.set(json_data)
```

I am able to avoid the error by wrapping the initialization with an if-else block, but somehow I feel that this implementation is messy (not really graceful). Is there a better way than this?

```
if not firebase_admin._apps:
    firebase_admin.initialize_app()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says:

> The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument.

You need to call `initialize_app()` only once as it only needs to be initialized once.

The best solution is to write `firebase_admin.initialize_app()` outside `my_function()`.

Comment: awesome! it worked lol. kinda dumb for me to not have thought of that.